# WebSockets continuation frames are not supported

Tags: python

```
1692952517,["admin","init",[0,4,2081],["Chromium at 2023-08-25T14:05:17.011336","Chromium"],"jaxAfsVenShp8dYtwTJTKQ==",true]
```

**Error:**

```
error b'\x88\x1f\x03\xefText Frames are not supported
```

Kindly guide error after socket open wss://web.whatsappcom/ws/chat

Comment: What solution you are expecting from the provided info? Check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: whatsapp web version and string format for sending qr code  request

Comment: What is the current *whatsapp web version and string format for sending qr code request*? Can you [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76978526/edit) post with more details?